# Adding “&nbsp;” before the last word in multiple defined areas with a plugin

Tags: plugins, posts, characters

How would this be done with javascript or a plugin? This would prevent widows from happening in my WordPress posts. Shaun Inman has created a similar plugin for post titles, but not for actual posts. Can his plugin be modified to include posts?

http://shauninman.com/archive/2006/08/22/widont_wordpress_plugin

Here is a screenshot of my post with a widow:

http://cl.ly/image/0A0j383H0Z2U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop in `add_filter( 'the_content', 'widont' );` (and the same for `the_excerpt` if required).

This'll apply the function to the post content in addition to the title (`the_title`).

Comment: That worked! I added that line of code directly underneath `add_filter('the_title', 'widont');`